# how to use a shared cache in okhttp

Tags: java, okhttp

Is it possible to use the okhttp cache in a shared manner, ie: having multiple clients accessing the same cache directory in order to avoid having to each keep their own.

In the [repices of the okhttp wiki](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes) we find:

> It is an error to have multiple caches accessing the same cache directory simultaneously

I am not looking for different caches to use the same folder, but rather a single shared cache that can be updated by more than one client.

A simple example would be (in Java) running:

```
    Cache cache = new Cache(cacheDirectory, cacheSize);

    client  = new OkHttpClient.Builder().cache(cache).build();
    client2 = new OkHttpClient.Builder().cache(cache).build();
```

Would this be unsafe to do? If so, is there an alternative to achieve this or is it not possible at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep, that's completely safe. It would be unsafe to have multiple instances of `Cache` that share a directory, whether in one process or multiple.

Comment: Hello Jesse, if I understand you correctly, it should be safe to create multiple OkHttp clients as long as they use the same `Cache` object. Is this correct? Will the shared `Cache` object make sure the clients don't try to write to the same cache simultaneously?

Comment: If this is correct, would it be safe to store the `Cache` object as a singleton and use it for multiple OkHttp clients at the same time?

Comment: Yeah, you definitely want a singleton